# Can prayers manifest a wish? Is there any significance to prayer according to hinduism

Tags: gods, mantras, prayer, manuscripts, paramatma

Do prayers hold any real benefit and significance with respect to the karmic functioning of the universe. Can communal prayers i.e. numerous people praying or asking for something manifest a wish?

Comment: Short answer, yes. Devas (deities) grant boons (wishes). Prayers are directed towards Devas and the power of the devas (as well as the Asuras), are directly dependent upon the belief of the people partly derived through these prayers.

Comment: Well if your question amounts to scientific evidence then there is none but why don't you try it and let us know? Make a small wish, pray and insert a time constraint and let us know what happened.